# if / elseif from base template

Tags: templating

I have a hero textbox that I would like to control from the base template using a simple if/elseif.

I have a field called "hero" for the homepage. For pages in the "Small Groups" section, I want the hero to say "Groups." For everything else, I want it to be the entry title.

It seems straightforward, but this isn't working? It is ignoring the elseif.

```
{% if entry == craft.entries.section('homepage') %}
    {{ entry.hero }}
{% elseif entry == craft.entries.section('smallgroups') %}
    Groups
{% else %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is probably that you're actually comparing an [EntryModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entrymodel) (`entry`) to an [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) (the array-like object used for querying entries, which is returned by the `craft.entries` call).

Something like this should do it:

```
{% if entry.section.handle == 'homepage' %}
    {{ entry.hero }}
{% elseif entry.section.handle == 'smallgroups' %}
    Groups
{% else %}
    {{ entry.title }}
{% endif %}
```

Assuming your section handles are correct, the above should work – although this is a perfect use for using the [`{% switch %}`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/switch) tag instead of `{% if %}`, which in my opinion would make your code more readable:

```
{% switch entry.section.handle %}
    {% case 'homepage' %}
        {{ entry.hero }}
    {% case 'smallgroups' %}
        Groups
    {% default %}
        {{ entry.title }}
{% endswitch %}
```

Comment: `{% switch %}` worked perfectly. I thought those only worked with matrix fields. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @JeffFulton Nah, it's just a variation on the if/else statement. You can always get by with the latter, but code-wise it's often more concise when your conditional is based around multiple possible values for a single variable. To be clear, the use of if/else wasn't the reason your original code didn't work; it was the fact that you were comparing an EntryModel to an ElementCriteriaModel.